# Need guidance on creating a new object that stores user information after comparing it

Tags: arrays, performance, powershell, linq, comparison

I have some code that I will show below; that compares 2 objects using LINQ. There are 2 variables I have. 1 is the comparison of new items that need to be added, and the other is of items that need to be deleted.

When I do the comparison it works fine, but it compares firstnames first, then middle initial, then lastname and so forth. When I print out the variable at the very end it print it out in the same order. first names first then middle initial then last names...

What I am trying to do instead is organize it in a table that outputs it in order so for example it outputs the user and all of it's attributes.

Here is my code.

```
#Our Array of values we will be comparing
[array]$CompareValues = "FirstName","MiddleName","LastName","DisplayName","Email","Mobile","TelephoneNumber","Title","Dept","Company"

for($i=0; $i -lt $CompareValues.Count; $i++)
{
    #First let's create 2 variables that will hold the info we want
    $A = ($Users).($CompareValues[$i])
    $B = ($Contacts).($CompareValues[$i])

    ##################### Compare existing contacts to Users #####################

    #Only Run if there are contacts; otherwise there is nothing for us to compare
    if(($NULL -ne $B))
    {
        #Displays what accounts we need to import
        $NeedsToBeAdded += [string[]]([Linq.Enumerable]::Except([object[]]$a, [object[]]$b))

        #Displays what accounts we need to delete because they no longer exist
        $NeedsToBeDeleted += [string[]]([Linq.Enumerable]::Except([object[]]$b, [object[]]$a))
    }
}
```

Here is how it prints (as an example)

```
Bob 
Mary
John

Jones
Joe
Nowak

Bjones
Mjoe
Jnowak

bjones@domain.com
mjoe@domain.com
jnowak@domain.com

123-456-7890
123-456-7891
123-456-7892

Manager
Accountant
Engineer

HR
Accounting
IT

CompanyName
CompanyName
CompanyName
```

And here is how I would like it to print as an example (no delimiter necessary I'm just using the comma for readability)

```
Bob , , Jones, Bjones, bjones@domain.com, 123-456-7890, , Manager, HR, CompanyName
Mary , , joe, Mjoe, mjoe@domain.com, 123-456-7891, , Accountant, Accounting, CompanyName
John , , Nowak, Jnowak, jnowak@domain.com, 123-456-7892, , Engineer, IT, CompanyName
```

How can I achieve something like this? My end goal is after I get it all stored in the variable correctly, I will go through each object and then update the contact list either add the new users with the attributes above, or delete the user and their contact info because they no longer exist.

Comment: Not really clear what you displayed as output. Are those the users that need to be added or deleted? If you have two object arrays, `$Users` and `$Contacts`, then why not simply check on the property that should be unique like `Email` and output the differences as object arrays, so they are easy to display in table format, output to CSV etc..

Comment: That bit of code is a small portion of what the whole script does. The whole script imports new contacts. It get's a list of users from AD, then uses that list (stored in $Users) to compare existing Contacts in Exchange in a users mailbox. 

1 variable holds new users (user exists in $Users, but doesn't exist in Contacts"; the other variable holds users that need to be deleted (user exists in $Contacts, but not in $Users; therefore delete that contact and its properties )

Comment: Also I am comparing multiple variables because a contact that may already exist in Exchange may have a different title, or phone number. So I need to compare all variables with that from AD (in $Users). I hope that makes sense.  In your comment above, how else would I compare it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're only updating a contact if that specific value is not in the list already, which will cause problems. For example, let's look at last names:

```
$Users.LastName $Contacts.LastName
--------------- ------------------
Smith           Joe     # 
Joe-Jones       Joe     #
Smith           Nowak   ## These three changed
Smith           Smith
Joe             Joe
Nowak           Nowak
```

If you were to compare these by name, your script would only return one new entry. Here, two users have changed their last name to smith:

```
$A = ($Users).LastName
$B = ($Contacts).LastName

$NeedsToBeAdded += [string[]]([Linq.Enumerable]::Except([object[]]$a, [object[]]$b))
$NeedsToBeAdded

#Outputs:
Joe-Jones  # Missing two changes!
```

"Smith" was already in the contacts list, so no difference is seen.

Instead, you'll need to compare each entire object, or have some kind of unique ID to match users and contacts on. The simplest answer for what you have is `Compare-Object` where you add all the properties you want to compare on:

```
$Diff = Compare-Object $Users $Contacts -Property FirstName,LastName,Email -PassThru

$NeedsToBeAdded   = $diff | Where SideIndicator -eq '=>'
$NeedsToBeDeleted = $diff | Where SideIndicator -eq '<='
```

`-PassThru` lets it output the a original object:

```
$NeedsToBeAdded | ft FirstName,LastName,Email

FirstName LastName  Email            
--------- --------  -----            
Bob       Smith     bjones@domain.com
Mary      Joe-Jones mjoe@domain.com  
John      Smith     jnowak@domain.com
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. This worked great for my needs. I'm a little surprised that I didn't know that about the LINQ method before. I've read on several other threads/forums/blogs that using LINQ is the most efficient and best way of doing it (outside of it being a little challenging). Thanks again.